# React-Redux: Using action creators in React components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React/Redux, and appreciate your help. I am taking a Udemy course on this topic. The course instructor creates a component like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchUser } from '../actions';

class User extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchUser(this.props.userId);
    }

    render(){
        const { user } = this.props;

        if(!user) return null;

        return(
            <div className="header"> User Info: {user.name}</div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return { user: state.users.find( user => user.id === ownProps.userId)};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUser })(User)
```

**my question:** why inside the `componentDidMount()` he is prefixing `fetchUsers()` with `this.props`?
it is not the case that he is passing `fetchUsers()` as props from the parent component. This is how the parent is using this component `<User userId={post.userId}/>`

**Note:** this code works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of this line :

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUser })(User)`

the second parameter to `connect` is called `mapDispatchToProps`, It adds the actions to props

From the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) :

> connect can accept an argument called mapDispatchToProps, which lets
>   you create functions that dispatch when called, and pass those
>   functions as props to your component.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
    decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
    reset: () => dispatch({ type: 'RESET' })
  }
}
```

Your code is using the “object shorthand” form.

Answer (score 2):

The way the `mapDispatchToProps` in the example is shorthanded. It might be easier to tell what is going if it was written like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchUser } from '../actions';

class User extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchUser(this.props.userId);
    }

    render(){
        const { user } = this.props;

        if(!user) return null;

        return(
            <div className="header"> User Info: {user.name}</div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return { user: state.users.find( user => user.id === ownProps.userId)};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
  fetchUser
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(User)
```

Maybe this shows it more clearly, but the dispatch function (`fetchUser`) is being mapped to the components properties. Just like the state value (user) is being mapped to the properties of the component. I think you just got confused because of the shorthand that was used.

Comment: I agree that it is simpler to view it that way but you can actually just do `const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchUser }` and that is all you need to do